# simple question about covariance

Tags: probability

Let $x,y,z$ be three random variables. How can you show that:
$$\operatorname{cov}(x+y,z) = \operatorname{cov}(x,z) + \operatorname{cov}(y,z)$$ by using the definition of covariance.

Comment: Please show your attempt.Since youre new to this community, i did commented, instead of downvoted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the fact that $cov(X,Y)=E(X-EX)(Y-EY)$ and rearrange the terms.
I've included the full solution below, just move the mouse on the grey area.

> \begin{align*}
>    cov(x+y,z)&=E[(x+y-E(x+y))(z-Ez)]\\
>    &=E[((x-Ex)+(y-Ey))(z-Ez)]\\
>    &=E(x-Ex)(z-Ez)+E(y-Ey)(z-EZ)=cov(x,z)+cov(y,z)
>    \end{align*}